# SQL - Sum with Group BY and Max

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following sample table where I need to have sum of columns values where VA1 and Val2 are same , need to sum cvalue and seelct the ID where cValue is max

```
+---------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ Val1 ¦ Val2 ¦ CValue ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 1  ¦ 1    ¦ 1    ¦ 1      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 2  ¦ 1    ¦ 1    ¦ 9      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 3  ¦ 1    ¦ 1    ¦ 1      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 4  ¦ 5    ¦ 3    ¦ 2      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 5  ¦ 5    ¦ 3    ¦ 8      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 6  ¦ 7    ¦ 5    ¦ 8      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 7  ¦ 8    ¦ 9    ¦ 4      ¦
+---------------------------+
```

for above raw data below is the required output:

```
+---------------------------+
¦ ID ¦ Val1 ¦ Val2 ¦ CValue ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 2  ¦ 1    ¦ 1    ¦ 11     ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 4  ¦ 5    ¦ 3    ¦ 10     ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 6  ¦ 7    ¦ 8    ¦ 8      ¦
¦----+------+------+--------¦
¦ 7  ¦ 8    ¦ 9    ¦ 4      ¦
+---------------------------+
```

Can someone help to provide the right query to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: _someone help to provide the right query..._ What queries have you been trying so far?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: ID 4 is not " the ID where cValue is max". And what to do in case of ties, when there are two or more IDs all with the same max value?

Comment: And I have the same question as B001ᛦ: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You are supposed to come here with a concrete problem. What is yours? What keeps you from writing the query?

Comment: Simple group by won't work due to condition for Max(ID), I will try the other queries and get back to you all. Thanks for responses,

Comment: `select grid.LONGITUDE, grid.LATITUDE,sum(grid.MRSUM) as totalMR, 
case when GRID.MRSUM > GRID2.MRSUM THEN GRID.SERVCELLID  ELSE GRID2.SERVCELLID END AS SERVICECELLID
 from naspa.R_GEO_GRID_L_31515 grid, naspa.R_GEO_GRID_L_31515 grid2  
 where 
    GRID.LONGITUDE = GRID2.LONGITUDE and GRID.LATITUDE = GRID2.LATITUDE 

group by grid.LONGITUDE, grid.LATITUDE, case when GRID.MRSUM > GRID2.MRSUM THEN GRID.SERVCELLID ELSE GRID2.SERVCELLID END`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This, using `KEEP..DENSE_RANK`

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c82f51/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (ID int, Val1 int, Val2 int, CValue int)
;

INSERT ALL 
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (1, 1, 1, 1)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (2, 1, 1, 9)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (3, 1, 1, 1)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (4, 5, 3, 2)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (5, 5, 3, 8)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (6, 7, 5, 8)
    INTO yourtable (ID, Val1, Val2, CValue)
         VALUES (7, 8, 9, 4)
SELECT * FROM dual
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT MAX(ID) KEEP (
        DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY cvalue DESC
        ) as ID
    ,Val1
    ,Val2
    ,SUM(CValue) AS CValue
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Val1
    ,Val2
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c82f51/5/0)**:

```
| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 | CVALUE |
|----|------|------|--------|
|  2 |    1 |    1 |     11 |
|  5 |    5 |    3 |     10 |
|  6 |    7 |    5 |      8 |
|  7 |    8 |    9 |      4 |
```

Comment: Good answer (as long as OP doesn't want to deal with ties differently). `FIRST ORDER BY cvalue DESC` is simply `LAST ORDER BY cvalue` of course.

Comment: Worked like Charm.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t2.id,t1.Val1,t1.Val2, SUM(t1. CValue ) AS sum 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT id,Val1,Val2 FROM Table1 
 WHERE cvalue IN (SELECT MAX(cvalue) FROM table1 GROUP BY Val1,Val2)) t2
ON t1.Val1 =t2.Val1 AND t1.Val2 =t2.Val2 
GROUP BY t1.Val1,t1.Val2,t2.id
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Output

```
ID  VAL1 VAL2   SUM
2   1    1      11
5   5    3      10
6   7    5      8
7   8    9      4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Val1, Val2, SUM(CValue) AS sum 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Val1, Val2 
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

You can't select the ID without having some kind of aggregation strategy for it (there's no method by which it can be implicitly grouped).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
SQL> with test (id, val1, val2, cvalue) as
  2    (select 1, 1, 1, 1 from dual union
  3     select 2, 1, 1, 9 from dual union
  4     select 3, 1, 1, 1 from dual union
  5     select 4, 5, 3, 2 from dual union
  6     select 5, 5, 3, 8 from dual union
  7     select 6, 7, 5, 8 from dual union
  8     select 7, 8, 9, 4 from dual
  9    ),
 10  inter as
 11    (select id, val1, val2,
 12       sum(cvalue) over (partition by val1, val2) cvalue,
 13       row_number() over (partition by val1, val2 order by cvalue desc) rn
 14     From test t
 15    )
 16  select id, val1, val2, cvalue
 17  from inter
 18  where rn = 1
 19  order by id;

        ID       VAL1       VAL2     CVALUE
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         2          1          1         11
         5          5          3         10
         6          7          5          8
         7          8          9          4

SQL>
```

Note, though, the difference in IDs: you have ID = 4, while I have ID = 5 instead. Why? Because you said that you want to "select the ID where cValue is max". For VAL1 = 5 and VAL2 = 3 (rows with IDs 4 and 5), max cValue is 8, and it belongs to ID = 5.

Also, row for ID = 6 whould be 6-7-5-8, not 6-7-8-8.

Answer (score 0):

If you select distinct values from your table and then sum the cvalue whcih is linked to them, that should do the trick?

```
select distinct [val1], [val2] ,sum([cvalue])  from [table] group by [val1], [val2]
```

Comment: No. Aggregation (`GROUP BY`) happens first. On its result you are then applying the superfluous `DISTINCT`. The brackets are invalid SQL and will result in an exception in Oracle.

Comment: And what problem are you trying to address with `DISTINCT` anyway?

Comment: Well, if you will select distinct and then sum the value it will give you the results that Rehan Azher was asking for, right? The only missing part will be ID which you can get after you join the table?

Comment: No. If `DISTINCT` happened before `GROUP BY` (which it doesn't), you'd only remove one of the two rows for Val1=1, Val2=1, CValue=1, which is the only duplicate. But the sum shall include both rows, as you can see from the example. I guess you misread this somehow.